# Genitive relative pronoun vs. personal pronoun in this Kafka sentence

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun

The question is on this sentence from Kafka's Der Prozess.

> »Was wäre denn zu sagen?«, antwortete K., der dessen müde war, die Augen des Fräulein Montag fortwährend auf seine Lippe gerichtet zu sehen.

**QUESTION**

1. Is *dessen* a genitive relative pronoun?
2. If yes to 1, why does Kafka use it instead of *seiner*, the genitive personal pronoun, which would seem to make more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[einer Sache] müde sein* is an expression used to say "to be tired of [something]". Note that "einer Sache" is in the genitive form.

So *dessen* is the genitive of *das* = "the thing he was tired of". In this case, that's the fact that Miss Montag kept staring at his lips.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a relative pronoun, but a demonstrative pronoun, referring forward to the infinitive construction: tired of seeing. Replacing it with the personal pronoun *seiner* would render the sentence ungrammatical because the infinitive no longer would be connected to the rest; it would also change the meaning, as K. then would be tired of some previously mentioned person.

Comment: My Anglophone mind was looking for *es* (hence *seiner*) even after seeing *das* for this sort of thing (also in *darum*, *dafür* etc.) countless times! I am "choosing" the other answer to encourage the member with a lower reputation.