# "das" vs "es" to refer to a long phrase or clause

Tags: pronoun

The question is on *es* as highlighted in this passage from Kafka's Der Prozess.

> Im übrigen erzählte sie mir erst gestern und nur ganz flüchtig davon, sie sagte hierbei, daß auch Ihnen jedenfalls nicht viel an der Unterredung liegen könne, denn Sie wären nur durch einen Zufall auf einen derartigen Gedanken gekommen und würden selbst auch ohne besondere Erklärung, wenn nicht schon jetzt, so doch sehr bald die Sinnlosigkeit des Ganzen erkennen. Ich antwortete darauf, daß das richtig sein mag, daß ich **es** aber zur vollständigen Klarstellung doch für vorteilhaft hielte, Ihnen eine ausdrückliche Antwort zukommen zu lassen.

**QUESTION**

It seems that *das* (in isolation <strike>or as part of compounds like *dafür*, *darum* and *davon*</strike>) mostly stands for long phrases and clauses when that's convenient, but sometimes *es* is used.

1. Why is it *es* and not *das* in the sentence quoted?
2. Are there any general principles on when to use *das* vs. *es* and when either would do?

**BACKGROUND**

See this [other post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29148/genitive-relative-pronoun-vs-personal-pronoun-in-this-kafka-sentence), where I learned that *seiner* could not refer to an infinitive clause.

Comment: I said that *das* occurred in a compound like *davon*, but I was wrong. It seems *das* and *da* are not even etymologically related. For *davon* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/davon#Etymology; for *da* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/da#Etymology_7; for *das* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/das#Etymology_5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, both *das* and *es* can be used to refer to concepts that have been mentioned before (backward reference or anaphoric reference) or that will be mentioned shortly (forward reference or cataphoric reference). There are, however, a number of restrictions regarding which can be used for what.

In a forward reference, *das* can only be used to refer to a following relative clause, not any other kind of clause:

> Ich tue das, was ich für vorteilhaft halte.

In Kafka’s second sentence, the intention is to refer to *Ihnen eine ausdrückliche Antwort zukommen zu lassen*, which is an infinitive construction, not a relative clause. Therefore, *das* can’t be used. In a backward reference, on the other hand, *das* is more flexible. (Note that the reference in this case is optional.) Consider these examples for cataphoric *das* (not grammatical), anaphoric *das* and no reference:

> <s>Ich halte *das* für vorteilhaft, Ihnen zu antworten.</s>
>   Ihnen zu antworten, *das* halte ich für vorteilhaft.
>   Ihnen zu antworten, halte ich für vorteilhaft.

Unlike *das*, *es* can be used for a forward reference to an infinitive, as in Kafka’s sentence, or to a *dass/daß* subordinate clause:

> Ich halte *es* für vorteilhaft, Ihnen zu antworten.
>   *Es* ist schön, dass heute die Sonne scheint.

But it cannot be used as a backward reference in the same way as *das*, unless the reference is to a complete sentence; but even then *das* would be preferred:

> <s>Ihnen zu antworten, *es* halte ich für vorteilhaft.</s>
>   <s>Ihnen zu antworten, ich halte *es* für vorteilhaft.</s>
>   Ich will Ihnen antworten. (?)Ich halte *es* für vorteilhaft.
>   Ich will Ihnen antworten. Ich halte *das* für vorteilhaft.

There are further restrictions; e.g., *es* can’t be used together with a preposition, and a pronominal adverb is used instead:

> <s>Wir müssen *an es* denken, die Blumen zu gießen.</s>
>   Wir müssen *daran* denken, die Blumen zu gießen.

---

As an aside: In light of the above, it is clear that the *das* in *daß das richtig sein mag* can’t be referring to the following *daß* clause, but must mean something that was mentioned before. This is a useful parsing hint for the reader.

Comment: Am I OK to think that *es* as a reference to a phrase or clause can only occur in the nominative or accusative, but never in the dative or genitive? (As for the dative, when would a clause ever be in it? Maybe if, in some technical discussion, you had many propositions on the board and were saying, 'P entspricht Q'? And if you ever wanted to replace Q with a pronoun, could that be *ihm*?)

Comment: For a forward reference, you would probably use a noun, which is always an option: _Ich unterstütze **es** [acc], jetzt nach Hause zu gehen._ = _Ich unterstütze **den Vorschlag** [acc], jetzt nach Hause zu gehen._ But only: _Ich stimme **dem Vorschlag** [dat] zu, jetzt nach Hause zu gehen._ – For a backward reference in dative, I think _ihm_ wouldn’t be possible, only _dem_: _Jetzt nach Hause zu gehen, **dem** stimme ich zu._

Answer (score 2):

"Es" is being used since the expression "[direct object] für vorteilhaft halten" needs a direct object. 
In this case the direct object "es" refers to the idea or plan "Ihnen eine ausdrückliche Antwort zukommen zu lassen" and not the previously mentioned question or fact. If "das" would be chosen, the sentence would make no sense anymore, since it would then refer to an object from the previous sentence, which Kafka is actually already referring to in the first part of the sentence when he uses "das" in "daß das richtig sein mag".

For further clarification, the "es" could also be substituted with the last part of the sentence:

> Ich antwortete darauf, daß das richtig sein mag, daß ich Ihnen eine
>   ausdrückliche Antwort zukommen zu lassen aber zur vollständigen
>   Klarstellung doch für vorteilhaft hielte.

This would make it even more complex and hard to read/understand. Just looking at the second part of the sentence, an easier example using "warten" instead of the last sentence would be:

> Ich antwortete darauf, daß das richtig sein mag, daß ich es aber zur
>   vollständigen Klarstellung doch für vorteilhaft hielte, zu warten.

would become

> Ich antwortete darauf, daß das richtig sein mag, daß ich Warten aber zur
>   vollständigen Klarstellung doch für vorteilhaft hielte.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use "es", because this personal pronoun is a representative for the following subclause ("*Ihnen eine ausdrückliche Antwort zukommen zu lassen*"), whereas "das" would be used to replace this subclause. Use "es" if a subclause is to be included in the sentence.

This is very well illustrated by the first subclause ("daß das richtig sein mag"). The object to which "das" refers is omitted.

The length of the phrase is not relevant.